# Ruby on rails implementing "repost" action for Post's model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a `User`and `Post` model  with the association `one-to-many`. I tried to implement a repost action, add a link `has_and_belongs_to_many` through a table `reposts`.

But I was faced with the following challenges:

1) Post to feed loaded as follows:

```
followed_users="SELECT  followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user ";
replics_posts="SELECT micropost_id FROM replics_users WHERE user_id = (:user)"
reposts="SELECT post_id FROM reposts WHERE user_id = (:user)"

where("user_id IN(#{followed_users}) OR user_id= (:user) OR id IN(#{replics_posts}) OR id in (#{reposts})", user: user);
```

and sorted by date modified. Repost similarly sorted, from which there is a situation that is repost in the middle  feed.

2) No additional effort, followers do not see reposts user.

These problems can be solved through the auxiliary array with the need to fast, but it looks ridiculous and non-optimal solution.

How can I get out of the situation?

P.S. I think the solution can be found by reference in the field "Content" in the `Post` model on the same field, another object. Then repost action will not need a separate table and will consist only of a new `Post` object with a pointer to the contents of the original post. But I do not know how to do this in Ruby on Rails.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected as follows:

1)  In the `Post` model added a new field `repost_id` and reference to yourself:

```
has_many: reposts, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "repost_id", dependent:: destroy;
```

(relation to the model `User` not changed)

2) Added to `Post`'s controller method `repost`

```
  def repost
    orig_post=Micropost.find(params[:id]);
    if(orig_post)
      Micropost.create(user_id:current_user.id, 
        content: orig_post.content, 
        repost_id:orig_post.id);
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end 
    end 
  end
```

(Do not forget to realize meets both the route and validations creation of the post)

The result is a correct model of behavior actions repost with dependencies and correct display in the feed. But sadly, this approach involves storing duplicate data in the table `Posts` in the "Content" field.